# Primary Key Validation in Snowflake datawarehouse

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

1. Is there a primary key validation in Snowflake
2. If not, how are inserts handled on Snowflake side (do we simply end up with duplicate rows?)
3. If the answer to 2 is yes, how are subsequent deletes and updates handled against these possible duplicate rows?

Answer (score 3):

1) Snowflake supports defining and maintaining constraints, but does not enforce them, except for NOT NULL constraints, which are always enforced.

https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/constraints-overview.html

2) Yes, they end up with duplicate rows.

3) You may use WINDOWING functions to specify which duplicate row is deleted:

https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00008EJgemSAD/how-to-delete-duplicate-records-

Answer (score 0):

[Unistore](https://www.snowflake.com/en/data-cloud/workloads/unistore/) (currently in private preview) is Snowflake's OLTP offering, and handles primary key validation automatically (like any traditional OLTP database).